# SIM Card router not getting connected to SIM network

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have a SIM card connected to a router. In an old phone it works just fine, but the router cannot connect to the SIM Card network, and although it generates it's own wifi, that wifi does not have access to the internet.

I am wondering why this can be. Both the router and the card are carrier free (I am from Spain, this is an option here at least). It seems that there is something I am missing, maybe I should delete the PIN from the SIM Card but I don't know how to do it.

Would someone give me some input about how to solve this?

The carrier is R.

Comment: If the router has a SIM-card reader and thus supports cellular is should have a web interface for configuring the SIM PIN. Alternatively you can use your old phone to change the SIM PIN. usually there should be also an option to disable the PIN.

Comment: To add to @Robert, sometimes from the web interface, regardless of whether or not you have to enter the PIN, you usually do have to press connect at least once.

Comment: I've checked and the APN is ok, and the PIN is disabled by default. Hmmm... how extrange

Comment: You might have to enter 0000 as pin then

Comment: Is it a MVNO? If so you may need to tweak the APN settings. Please [edit] the question and add the carrier. I'm currently in Spain an I might be able to help you.

Comment: Edited @ChanganAuto

Comment: Oh, the infamous Galician "R". With some effort I could walk to their HQ right now (but I won't and it's closed anyway). Check this https://foros.mundo-r.com/foros/foro-mobil-r/10962-configuracion-modem-airbox and additionally you may need to add "default" or "default,supl" and/or setting the MVNO type and/or try different authentication settings. In a nutshell, always keep the basic settings and try additional settings, one at the time.

Comment: Ok, Thanks Changan! I'll take a look, I think by default the APN comes with default,supl and another value more